# Can I used mod_rewrite to change file extensions? .jpeg to .jpg for example

Tags: apache, file, mod-rewrite

I am looking to use Apache mod_rewrite to serve a file as .jpg instead of .jpeg. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just rename the file? It's generally bad practice to serve the same content on different URLs like this.

Comment: Ben S, isn't the entire point of mod_rewrite to serve the same content on different URLs?  What makes this generally bad practice?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.jpeg$ $1.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the **jpeg** extension to **jpg** using the following rule in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.jpeg$ /$1.jpg [L]
```