# hide file extensions with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How can you hide all file extentions like .php to counter SEO

```
/page => /page.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$           %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

This doesn't work...

#### edit

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/]*)$       /$1$2.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479167/can-i-used-mod-rewrite-to-change-file-extensions-jpeg-to-jpg-for-example

Comment: the question you are referring to has not specified the rules good enough

Comment: I didn't vote down, but I assume people voted down because this question is already covered.

Comment: have edited my question, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You've written some strange faults in your code!

- `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` already contains the file-extension, so you are asking for a file wich ends with `.php.php`, and with the `-f`-flag, you are checking if such a file exists. Also, there actually is no need to check if the requested file exists for what you want to do.
- Your RewriteRule would rewrite any dot-php-file to the same URL plus an additional `.php`. So `index.php` would become `index.php.php`
- What for is the exclamation mark at the very beginning of your RewriteRule?

Fixing these errors, you get something like:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1/
```

You can use `$1, $2, $...` in the right part of your expresison to access the n-th match between brackets () on the left.

For more information about mod_rewrite, see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Maybe it helps to look there from time to time. ;)

Comment: it still doesn't work.. have tried your solution.. have edited my question